# cancelling jquery draggable objects or reset

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i would like to load a page of objects that can be dragged on to a map/div but would like to have a clear/undo button? is this possible with jquery?

you can see code in a previous question

[jQuery UI droppables - changing the image that's dropped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175609/jquery-ui-droppables-changing-the-image-thats-dropped)

Comment: Assuming the dropped elements all have some sort of class couldn't you just $('.dropped').remove() when the clear button is clicked? You might need to give a little bit more information here.

Comment: idealy i would like to click a button that triggers something similar to revert to specific co-ordinates

Comment: I'm still uncertain what you're looking for. Could you give a full example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible with a simple call to `.animate()` (which, after all, is all jQueryUI is doing) and some logic to keep track of the original position of the element you're dragging (which jQueryUI already partially handles for you).

1. Keep track of the original position of your draggable elements using `.data()` and the `.drop()` event of your `droppable` object:

   ```
   $("#drop").droppable({
       drop: function(event, ui) {
           if (!ui.draggable.data("originalPosition")) {
               ui.draggable.data("originalPosition",
                   ui.draggable.data("draggable").originalPosition);
           }
       }
   });
   ```

   Basically this just sets data called "originalPosition" on the dragged element. This assumes that you're able to keep dragging the element inside a valid drop zone (and so it doesn't overwrite the original position after you keep dragging).
2. Create a function that you call that animates the dragged object back to its original position:

   ```
   function revertDraggable($selector) {
       $selector.each(function() {
           var $this = $(this),
               position = $this.data("originalPosition");

           if (position) {
               $this.animate({
                   left: position.left,
                   top: position.top
               }, 500, function() {
                   $this.data("originalPosition", null);
               });
           }
       });
   }
   ```

   Adjust the speed of the animation to your liking.
3. Call that function from an event handler:

   ```
   $("#undo").click(function() {
       revertDraggable($(".drag"));
   });
   ```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/v7N6w/

Comment: although for some reason the items arnt droppable in the working example- this is exactly what i need- it works in my code, you have saved my day

Comment: @Chris Mccabe: Good to hear it worked! I noticed some weirdness in the fiddle too; I chalked it up to weird stuff going on with the iframe. Dropping works in some parts of the droppable object. I guess I should call it a semi-working example `:)`