# Undo action if "cancel" is pressed in response to confirm()

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-ui-draggable, confirm

I made a quick list, which you can drag to a trash can (which removes it).

Everything works when you press "ok", and the item gets removed as it is told to.
Although if you press "cancel" to the confirm popup, the item shows up in the trash, and instead I want it to go back to where it was in the list.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gdze8/2/

Javascript:

```
   $( init )

    function init() {
    $(".contentItem").draggable({
        revert: 'invalid'
    });
    $(".list4").droppable( {
        accept: ".contentItem",

        drop: function(event, ui) {
            ui.draggable.hide();
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")){
            ui.draggable.remove();

            bottomInfo ();
        } else {
            ui.draggable.show();
        }
        return false;
        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583153/cancelling-jquery-draggable-objects-or-reset ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll add the confirm on the draggable instead, reverting if the confirm was not confirmed etc :

```
$(".contentItem").draggable({
    revert : function(event, ui) {
        var state = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
        if (state) $(this).remove();
        return !state;
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gdze8/4/)

Comment: If I do it this way, the code .remove(), is taken out, and the item never gets removed.

Comment: @BradleyMitchell - then just add the removal? Edited the answer!

Comment: Now I drag it anyway and it gets a popup message. The original program had it only so it would be dragged to the trash.

Comment: @BradleyMitchell - Then you add a condition to only allow dropping in the trash, here's a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gdze8/5/) ?