# Dragging/Dropping, returning to original position, and then dragging again with jquery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a bit of code where I'm dragging from a large list of object to a smaller list of objects. Once dragged, I want the ability to click a button and have the dragged object returned to the larger list.

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate the idea.
http://jsfiddle.net/q43ab/46/

However, as you can see, once returned the draggable cannot be dragged a second time. The fiddle is set up to use .html() to get the draggable div, and then use .html() again to set the draggable div back in it's original place, like so:

```
$(".remove").click(function(){
var removedbox = $(".candrop").html();
$(".candrop").empty();
//$(removedbox).appendTo(".holder:empty");
$(".holder:empty").html(removedbox);

// re-set any empty tiles to once again accept drops
$(".candrop").droppable("option", "accept", ".candrag");
});
```

I have also attempted to use the Cancel option in draggable, but to no avail (but maybe I wasn't doing it right).

Any idea how I might get this "drag, remove, drag again" functionality?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583153/cancelling-jquery-draggable-objects-or-reset

Comment: Thank you, but this was not quite what I was looking for. I didn't want an animation bringing it back, and the draggable wasn't necessarily going back to it's original starting location, just back to the larger list. Anywho, I solved the issue, but something tells me there's something funny going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution, though something tells me it may not be the best solution.

I had to re-define the .draggable function within the .click handler, as it seems that the new instance of the div was not being recognized by the original .draggable function despite having the appropriate class.

I've updated the fiddle to show the working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/q43ab/47/

The javascript as used in the fiddle:

```
$(".candrag").draggable({
  cursor: "move",
  helper: "clone",
  revert: "invalid",
  appendTo: ".candrop"
});

$(".candrop").droppable( {
  accept: ".candrag",
  hoverClass: "onhover",
  drop: onDrop
});

function onDrop( event, ui ) {
    var pos = $(this).position();
    $(ui.draggable).css({position: 'static', top: pos.top,left: pos.left}).draggable("option", "containment", "#currentteamcontainer").appendTo(this);

    // disallow the recent slot from accepting any more tiles
    $(this).droppable("option", "accept", "");
};

$(".remove").click(function(){
var removedbox = $(".candrop").html();
$(".candrop").empty();
//$(removedbox).appendTo(".holder:empty");
$(".holder:empty").html(removedbox);

//re-define the .draggable function within the .click remove event
$(".candrag").draggable({
  cursor: "move",
  helper: "clone",
  revert: "invalid",
  appendTo: ".candrop"
});

// re-set any empty tiles to once again accept drops
$(".candrop").droppable("option", "accept", ".candrag");

});
```

Hopefully it can help some other poor soul so they are not awake at 4am trying to figure this out.

ps. sorry if I got any terminology wrong, it's not my strong suit.